# Hide Taskbar in Windows 8

Tags: c#

Up to now, I was able to use the following C# code to hide the Windows taskbar:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int FindWindow(string className, string windowText);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int ShowWindow(int hwnd, int command);

private const int SW_HIDE = 0;
private const int SW_SHOW = 1;

...

int hwnd = FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", "");
ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
```

But when using Windows 8, this code only hides the taskbar on the primary monitor, not on the second, where the taskbar is also visible.

How may I hide the taskbar only on the screen where my windows are being shown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make use of [FindWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This allows you to pass in a window to search after in the Z order as well.

Ergo:

```
DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int FindWindowEx(int parent, int afterWindow, string className, string windowText);

// Start with the first child, then continue with windows of the same class after it
int hWnd = 0;
while (hWnd = FindWindowEx(0, hWnd, "Shell_TrayWnd", ""))
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
```

If you want to hide the task bar on a specific screen only, use [GetWindowRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and check the bounds for what screen the window is on, and only call ShowWindow on the window that is on the current screen.

Comment: "Second, what if your program crashes before it gets a chance to unhide the taskbar? The taskbar is now permanently hidden and the user has to log off and back on to get their taskbar back. That's not very nice."

Answer (score 9):

Don't hide the taskbar; that's the wrong way to do something like this. Instead, just make a fullscreen window, and the taskbar is smart enough to get out of your way.

You can read a good explanation & commentary by Microsoft's Raymond Chen on his [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/05/414910.aspx).

Comment: I totally agree with your opinion, but I need to get a window in front of another fullscreen application. Whenever my form gets the focus, the taskbar appears again.

Comment: If the taskbar appears when your window gets the focus, it may be that you're not setting a fullscreen window properly. Can you show us how you're creating your window?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem.

1) Running an application on multiple Monitors

2) On the first Monitor no problem, the Application stays on top

3) but if the second Window is clicked, the Task Bar appears and vice versa

With FindWindowEx only one Shell_TrayWnd is found. its the one from the first screen, which can be hidden