# Hide multiple Taskbar in Windows 8/10

Tags: c#

I have the following class to `Hide` or `Show` all `Taskbars`. But I get only one `handle` and so only one `taskbar` is hidden.

```
public static class Taskbar
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int ShowWindow(int hwnd, int command);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int FindWindowEx(int parent, int afterWindow, string className, string windowText);

    private const int _SW_HIDE = 0;
    private const int _SW_SHOW = 1;

    /// <summary>
    /// Show all taskbars
    /// </summary>
    public static void ShowAll()
    {
        int result = 0;
        do
        {
            result = FindWindowEx(0, result, "Shell_TrayWnd", null);
            ShowWindow(result, _SW_SHOW);
        }
        while (result != 0);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Hide all taskbars
    /// </summary>
    public static void HideAll()
    {
        int result = 0;
        do
        {
            result = FindWindowEx(0, result, "Shell_TrayWnd", null);
            ShowWindow(result, _SW_HIDE);
        }
        while (result != 0);
    }
}
```

---

I have used this snippet: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18257222/6229375

Do I have something wrong? I have 3 screens with 3 taskbars on windows 10.

Comment: It might be easier than you think: there is only one task bar. It's just visible on each screen (and I think that is a windows setting). There is no taskbar *per screen*.

Comment: And you may want to take the advice from the highest voted answer on the question you linked anyway.

Comment: So how can I hide the "other" taskbars if there is only one?
I catch every fatal exception in app.cs to restore the taskbar if my app would crash..

Comment: Maybe you should take a step back and ask why you want to have the taskbars different from what the user chose as his favorite setup.

Comment: I have a plc visualisation and the user should not be able to get into windows without "admin" rights for example. The problem is, that sometimes the main window is on top of the taskbar and sometimes the taskbar still appears. To get around of this annoying behavior I want to hide it.

Comment: Then you need something like [kiosk mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app). Hiding the taskbar is a cheap trick, not a solution to your problem. I mean all the key-combinations still work, even without the taskbar, so it's kinda pointless to hide it.